# AngularJS: Value arriving as null in service

Tags: angularjs, service, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass an object to my API, but when I do this for some reason the object becomes null. I cannot see the reason for this because I've done a similar process on multiple other occasions.

```
        var promiseGetRole = loginService.GetRole(user);
        promiseGetRole.then(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            $location.path('/UserManagement').replace();
            if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()

        },
        function (errorResult) {
            console.log("Unable to log in : " + errorResult);
        });
```

User is correctly populated.

```
//Get the Role of a given user
this.GetRole = function (user) {
    return $http.get(toApiUrl('login'), user);
}
```

Again, user is correctly populated at this point.

```
    //The user has been validated, now retrieve their role from the server
    public string Get(UserLogin user)
    {

        string role = "";

        //TODO: set role

        return role;

    }
```

It's at this point when it reaches the API the value for User just becomes null. I am using the same process in a post method (using UserLogin as the object being passed in) and cannot see any difference between them.

Comment: You need to make sure that the user object that gets sent from Angular is consistent with the UserLogin model that the Get action expects. Why don't you try just passing the user id as a URL parameter instead of sending the whole object in the request body?

Comment: Hi I did what you tried but id didn't fix it to begin with. I realised that the cause of the problem is that my service function is called GetRole and not just get. Otherwise I get an error - "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". Do you have any idea what is causing this? Obviously I might have multiple different methods that might Get based upon just the userID so it's not convenient.

Comment: The error you're getting is usually indicative of a cross domain request. Is the API application separate (i.e. under a different domain) from the website running the javascript code?

Comment: Ah I think the problem is that i have  [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] in my API which is restricting the names of my methods. I put that in off an example I was following and didn't give it much thought at the time. I think I'm just going to keep that there but split it off and give Roles it's own controller and service.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass data to the back-end like this(assuming you can retrieve roles by userId).:

```
var promise = $http.get(toApiUrl('login'), { params:{userId:user.Id}); // Only pass id in queryparams
...
```

You probably can pass the entire user object in the querystring but it has a length limit.

I don't know what you run back-end either so depending on that you might need to do different things to make it bind to the data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I realised that the cause of the problem is that my service function is called GetRole and not just get. Otherwise I get an error - "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". Do you have any idea what is causing this? Obviously I might have multiple different methods that might Get based upon just the userID so it's not convenient.

Comment: Seems you are doing a CORS request(Ajax request to a different domain). Also, if that backend is a .NET web.api controller i would recommend to use one API controller per model type i.e. one RoleController one UserController etc